# Sidebar Push Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I have the sidebar below, and what it's supposed to do is that when it is opened, it will push the items to the side, but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
 float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDBBSFnyl2fRlVY1ct1E6t5rUIFsu8JWmKeTrS9o1nnTigCOfI2g" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="55" height="55">

</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  <a href="#">Item 4</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Although, my code doesn't push the `div`s and the `image` to the side. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images and divs aren't being pushed with the sidebar because you're applying a margin-left to `#main`, and the images/divs exist outside of `#main`. Either put those elements inside of `#main` or apply the margin to `body` instead

Comment: Thanks! I would of never figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

Currently your image's arent inside the `#main` element. In order to get the movement you're after, its probably best to wrap all your "moving" content in a "containing" element, then apply the change to it.

Here we use `#wrapper` around everything except the menu, then set the `width:100%` and turn off `overflow-x` on the body, so that when pushed we dont get sideways scrollbars appear

**HTML**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDBBSFnyl2fRlVY1ct1E6t5rUIFsu8JWmKeTrS9o1nnTigCOfI2g" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="55" height="55">

    </div>

    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <div id="main">
        <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1,
#div2,
#div3,
#div4 {
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    transition: padding-left .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.paddingLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.paddingLeft = "0";
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2h37w6Lh/)**

---

As a personal preference though (to prevent the flash of your menu items changing width/wrapping to new lines), i would suggest keeping the menu's width consistent, and changing its `left` style property to move it in and out of view of the body like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2h37w6Lh/1/).